# Android :SQLite insert in Database

Tags: android, sqlite

i can not insert into database ,what is wrong wit this code.Thanks in advance.

```
public long insertGrille(Grille grille) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    //values.put(COL_ID, grille.getId());
    values.put(COL_X, grille.getxCoordinate());
    Log.i("COL_X, grille.getxCoordinate()", grille.getxCoordinate() + "");
    values.put(COL_Y, grille.getyCoordinate());
    values.put(COL_SSID, grille.getSsid());
    values.put(COL_RSSI, grille.getrssi());
    Log.i("insertion", values + "");
    Log.i("insertion", grille.getxCoordinate() + "");
    Log.i("insertion", bdd.insert(TABLE_RSSI, null, values) + "");
    return bdd.insert(TABLE_RSSI, null, values);
}
```

Creating data base :

```
public class MaBaseSQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final String TABLE_RSSI = "table_rssi";
private static final String COL_ID = "ID";
private static final String COL_X = "Xcoordinate ";
private static final String COL_Y = "Ycoordinate ";
private static final String COL_SSID = "SSID";
private static final String COL_RSSI = "RSSI";

private static final String CREATE_BDD = " CREATE TABLE " + " TABLE_RSSI " + " ("   + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_X + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_Y + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_SSID + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_RSSI + " TEXT NOT NULL);";  


public MaBaseSQLite(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
        int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(CREATE_BDD);
    Log.i("base créee","base créee");

}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE" +  TABLE_RSSI + ";");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}
**EDIT**

```
  case R.id.button1:
        Grille grille = new Grille(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, ssid, rssi);

        //livre.setIsbn(isbn);
        //livre.setTitre(titre);
        GrillePuissanceBDD liv = new GrillePuissanceBDD(getApplicationContext());
        liv.open();
        liv.insertGrille(grille);
        Log.i("grille***", grille + "");
        Log.i("getxCoordinate***", grille.getxCoordinate() + "");
        Grille livreFromBdd = liv.getGrilleWithTitre(grille.getxCoordinate());
        Log.i("livreFromBdd", livreFromBdd + "");
        if (livreFromBdd != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, livreFromBdd.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Prbleme", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        liv.close();
        break;
```

I'm not getting error ,and this the stack trace :

```
    04-16 04:47:34.700: I/creation base(9205): creation
04-16 04:47:34.860: I/COL_X, grille.getxCoordinate()(9205): xCoordinate
04-16 04:47:34.880: I/insertion(9205): Ycoordinate=yCoordinate RSSI=ssid Xcoordinate =xCoordinate SSID=rssi
04-16 04:47:34.880: I/insertion(9205): xCoordinate
04-16 04:47:34.990: I/insertion(9205): 29
04-16 04:47:35.020: I/grille***(9205): ID :0
04-16 04:47:35.020: I/grille***(9205): SSID : rssi
04-16 04:47:35.020: I/grille***(9205): X : xCoordinate
04-16 04:47:35.020: I/grille***(9205): Y : yCoordinate
04-16 04:47:35.020: I/grille***(9205): Puissance : ssid
04-16 04:47:35.020: I/getxCoordinate***(9205): xCoordinate
04-16 04:47:35.040: I/Cursor c(9205): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@41757ca8
04-16 04:47:35.110: I/c.getCount()(9205): 0
04-16 04:47:35.110: I/Cursor(9205): null
04-16 04:47:35.140: I/cursorTest(9205): ID :1
04-16 04:47:35.140: I/cursorTest(9205): SSID : 
04-16 04:47:35.140: I/cursorTest(9205): X : 
04-16 04:47:35.140: I/cursorTest(9205): Y : 
04-16 04:47:35.140: I/cursorTest(9205): Puissance : 
04-16 04:47:35.150: I/c.getCount()(9205): 0
04-16 04:47:35.150: I/livreFromBdd(9205): null
```

Comment: Show how do you create the db (the DB helper class).

Comment: What do you get as an error? Can you post the StackTrace?

Comment: Before inserting data in DB you have to Open database first.

Comment: Log cat, always include the log cat.

Comment: @Amina I should have been more precised, the **Exception stack trace**. It is usually in **red** and signifies the part of your code that failed.

Comment: HI, i'm a little confused about your code, what is bdd in the insertGrille method? is it a Writable SQliteDatabase??

Comment: @Olayinka as i said in the post ,i dont get any error and no exception :(

Comment: @Mouad.fkr : bdd : SQLiteDatabase bdd; and i created a methode open : `public void open()
    {
     bdd = mabaseSQLite.getWritableDatabase();
     Log.i("open","open" );
    }`

Comment: @Amina My apologies. Didn't see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually and really know exactly what's wrong with your code, this is why i try to give a simple working example to adapted with your situation :)

This is a simple example on how you can insert data into your DB:

let's take for example your DBHelper, i change make few changes to it (i'm making all private attribute public)

## MaBaseSQLite.java

```
    public class MaBaseSQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final String TABLE_RSSI = "table_rssi";
    public static final String COL_ID = "ID";
    public static final String COL_X = "Xcoordinate ";
    public static final String COL_Y = "Ycoordinate ";
    public static final String COL_SSID = "SSID";
    public static final String COL_RSSI = "RSSI";

    private static final String CREATE_BDD = " CREATE TABLE " + " TABLE_RSSI " + " ("   + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COL_X + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_Y + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_SSID + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_RSSI + " TEXT NOT NULL);";  


    public MaBaseSQLite(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(CREATE_BDD);
        Log.i("base créee","base créee");

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE" +  TABLE_RSSI + ";");
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

### }

Then let's create another activity:

## MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MaBaseSQLite dbHelper;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //intialisation de DBHelper
        dbHelper = new MaBaseSQLite(this, "MyDB", null, 1);

        //insertion des donnees
        insertGrille("12", "56", "rssi1", "ssid1");
                insertGrille("16", "14", "rssi2", "ssid2");
                insertGrille("10", "13", "rssi3", "ssid3");

        //recuperation des donnees
        getGrilles();

    }

    public void insertGrille(String x, String y, String rssi, String ssid){
        //get Writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        //Insert Data
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(MaBaseSQLite.COL_X, x);
        values.put(MaBaseSQLite.COL_Y, y);
        values.put(MaBaseSQLite.COL_RSSI, rssi);
        values.put(MaBaseSQLite.COL_SSID, ssid);

        db.insert(MaBaseSQLite.TABLE_RSSI, null, values);

        Log.i("MyTag", "data inserted");        

    }


    public void getGrilles() {
        //requete de recuperation
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + MaBaseSQLite.TABLE_RSSI;

        //get Readable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                //pour le moment je fais rien d'interessant avec ces donnees :)

                Log.i("MyTag", "grille.x= " + cursor.getString(1));
                Log.i("MyTag", "grille.y= " + cursor.getString(2));
                Log.i("MyTag", "grille.rssi= " + cursor.getString(3));
                Log.i("MyTag", "grille.ssid= " + cursor.getString(4));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }


}
```

And this is a simple test of the code:
[image]

Et bonne chance avec ton projet bataille navale :D

Let me know if something stills goes wrong! good luck

Comment: Thank you,but i want get something from the data base i get an excepttion : `Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: MyDB (code 1): , while compiling: select * from MyDB
`  I added this code ` Cursor cursorTest = db.rawQuery("select * from "+"MyDB", null);
        cursorTest.moveToFirst();
 int a = cursorTest.getInt(1);
 Log.i("a",a+"");` By the way merci :)

Comment: sorry for making you confused, Actually "MyDB" it's not a table it's the name i give to your database, the table is called "table_rssi", so if you want to make a select query you need to do it like this , "SELECT * FROM table_rssi" or "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_RSSI not select * from MyDB

Comment: Voila j'ai modifié le code pour qu'il match ton besoin, i tested in my computer and it's seems to be working just fine, you have just to drop the old database and start from scrutch again , or just unistall the app from your phone and rienstall it again, Bonne chance, let me know if there is anythiing not right ;)

Comment: THANK YOU ..vraiment vous m'avez sauvé la vie!!i passed all this morning trying to set up my old code, but your code is simple and right to the target :)

Comment: YOU ARE WELCOME ANYTIME, but never address to me with (vous) i'm just 22 yrs :p :D

Comment: Thank you :D bien entendu ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand what you've written but from what I've read.

These lines in your code show

```
private static final String COL_X = "Xcoordinate ";
private static final String COL_Y = "Ycoordinate ";
```

Remove the spaces at the end since you're using the same strings in the `ContentValues`

Also I'd advise you make access to the method `open` more restricted (`private`), call `open` in the method `insertGrille`.

Comment: Thank you :) i tryed to remove the blancks ,but still the same problem.